# Generate perodic messages with Omnet++ from same source node

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have a given network whose nodes have these two methods:

```
void Txc13::initialize()
{
    // Module 0 sends the first message
    if (getIndex() == 0) {
        // Boot the process scheduling the initial message as a self-message.
        TicTocMsg13 *msg = generateMessage();
        simtime_t delay = par("delayTime");
        scheduleAt(simTime()+delay, msg);
    }
}

void Txc13::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // we do some casting to access the fields inside the message
    TicTocMsg13 *ttmsg = check_and_cast<TicTocMsg13 *>(msg);

    if (ttmsg->getDestination() == getIndex()) {
        // Message arrived.
        bubble("ARRIVED!");
        delete ttmsg;
    }
    else {
        // We need to forward the message.
        forwardMessage(ttmsg);
    }
}
```

This works fine. Simulation ends oncce the message that has left node0 (`getIndex()==0`) arrives to its intended destination.

Now I'm willing to trigger several messages leaving `node0` after some `delay`.

Delay is exponentially distributed `network.tic[*].delayTime = exponential(10s)`.

How can I trigger several messages from the same node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. This is the code for both the methods. In the `initialize` method, I create an `event` message that I initially trigger at `t=0`.

```
void Txc13::initialize()
{
    // Create the event object we'll use for timing -- just any ordinary message.
    event = new cMessage("event");
    // Module 0 sends the first message
    if (getIndex() == 0) {
        scheduleAt(0.0, event);
    }
}
```

On the `handleMessage` method I check wether the incoming message is an `event` or not. If so, I do wait `simtime_t delay = par("delayTime")` which is exponentially distibuted and send out another self-message and forward on the message itself.

Since I want all messages to start at node0, I also check for that with `getIndex() == 0`.

```
void Txc13::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg == event and getIndex() == 0){
        TicTocMsg13 *msg = generateMessage();
        simtime_t delay = par("delayTime");
        scheduleAt(simTime()+delay, event);
        forwardMessage(msg);
    }
    else {
        // we do some casting to access the fields inside the message
        TicTocMsg13 *ttmsg = check_and_cast<TicTocMsg13 *>(msg);

        if (ttmsg->getDestination() == getIndex()) {
            // Message arrived.
            //EV << "Message " << ttmsg << " arrived after " << ttmsg->getHopCount() << " hops.\n";
            bubble("ARRIVED!");
            delete ttmsg;

            // Generate another one.
            //EV << "Generating another message: ";
            //TicTocMsg13 *newmsg = generateMessage();
            //EV << newmsg << endl;
            //forwardMessage(newmsg);
        }
        else {
            // We need to forward the message.
            forwardMessage(ttmsg);
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I obtain the following elog where you can appreciate that after each event, a message is forwarded.

[image]